# Where on Windows a named pipe file is stored?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am creating a named pipe file as follows:

```
 void  SavePipeFile(){


    HANDLE hpipe;
    BOOL bRet;
    DWORD size;

    hpipe =   
        CreateNamedPipe(
        L"\\\\.\\pipe\\mypipe",
        PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,  
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE,  
        1, 
        0,  
        0,  
        0,  
        NULL  
        );
    if(hpipe == NULL || hpipe==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Error opening handle\n");
    }

    CloseHandle(hpipe);


}
```

The function exists ok,no errors.But I can't find the physical file "mypipe" in the system.Does Windows API saves it to a specific location?Running on Windows 7 64bit

Comment: You created a *named pipe*, not a *named pipe file*. I have no idea why one would create a pipe and expect to get a file. After all, you have to have a very specific need to actually create a named pipe. It's not something you implement by accident.

Comment: I wanted a file as I need to specify it's location to an external app which needs to read it.Btw,on Linux I can have a file.

Comment: Named objects are referenced by their name. There is no requirement to have a physical file to reference a name pipe through it's name `\\.\pipe\mypipe`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quote from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe.

> Named pipes cannot be mounted within a normal filesystem, unlike in Unix. Also unlike their Unix counterparts, named pipes are volatile (removed after the last reference to them is closed). Every pipe is placed in the root directory of the named pipe filesystem (NPFS), mounted under the special path \.\pipe\ (that is, a pipe named "foo" would have a full path name of \.\pipe\foo). Anonymous pipes used in pipelining are actually named pipes with a random name.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a named pipe on ReactOS, `CreateNamedPipe` in kernel32.dll calls `NtCreateNamedPipeFile` in ntdll.dll, which performs a syscall + index into SSDT to its kernel mode counterpart in ntoskrnl.exe, which calls `IoCreateFile`, which calls `IopCreateFile`, which will call `ObOpenObjectByName`, which calls `ObpLookupObjectName`, which calls the object parse routine `ParseRoutine = ObjectHeader->Type->TypeInfo.ParseProcedure`, which will be `IopParseRoutine`, which sends an IRP with major code [IRP_MJ_CREATE_NAMED_PIPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/irp-mj-create-named-pipe) to the NPFS driver, which it acquires by its name `\Device\NamedPipe` (it will parse `\\.\pipe` as `\??\pipe`, which is a symbolic link to the `\Device\NamedPipe` DO created by the NPFS driver).

The `DriverEntry` function of the NPFS assigns `DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE_NAMED_PIPE] = NpFsdCreateNamedPipe;`. `NpFsdCreateNamedPipe` calls `NpCreateNewNamedPipe`, which will set up the file object and the CCB (Context Control Block) (`FileObject->FsContext2`) of the file object with the data queues.

The file object of name `PipeName` is accessed via `\\.\pipe\PipeName` and translates to `\Device\NamedPipe\PipeName`. The file object points to the `NamedPipe` device object created by the Npfs, which `IoGetRelatedDeviceObject` will return, meaning that all `WriteFile` and `ReadFile` operations result in an IRP, which gets sent to the top of the device stack of this Device Object, passing the pipe name `\PipeName`. This is similar to how `\??\C:\Windows` i.e. `\Device\HarddiskVolume1\Windows` file object `PDEVICE_OBJECT` points to the `Device\HarddiskVolume1` device object, the file name `UNICODE_STRING` of the file object being `\Windows`. If you look at the file object, you can get the full path by getting the device object name and appending it to the start. `IoCallDriver` will be eventually called on the owning driver of the device object. Based on the IRP major code in the IRP passed, `IoCallDriver` calls either `DO->DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_Write]`, which is `NpFsdWrite` or `DO->DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_Read]`, which is `NpFsdRead`. Those functions will write and read to the data queues `Ccb->DataQueue[FILE_PIPE_OUTBOUND]` and `Ccb->DataQueue[FILE_PIPE_INBOUND]`, which contain the head of a doubly linked list of `DataEntry` headers where `DataEntry[0]` is the header and `DataEntry[1]` is the buffer. If you open the named pipe as a server then it reads from the inbound and writes to the outbound. The client reads from the outbound and writes to the inbound.

If you use `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE`, then every time you write to the pipe, another `DataEntry` will be added to the tail of the linked list (because `NpWriteDataQueue` will return with `IoStatus` `STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED` in the IRP, which the calling function checks before calling `NpAddDataQueueEntry`), and each time you read, a `DataEntry` will be removed from the head of the linked list (`NpReadDataQueue` will only call `NpRemoveDataQueueEntry` if `!Peek`). You will get an error if you do not read all of the message. If you use `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE`, then only the current `DataEntry` is used and no `DataEntry`s are removed when you write. Simply, the `ByteOffset` field of the `DataEntry` is increased by the number of bytes read, and I'm really not sure how writing in byte mode works.

DataEntries, CCBs and FileObjects are allocated on the non-paged pool.

Comment: @KenWhite I grammatised it but that was my first draft; I need to check some stuff. The only issue is really that it may be too technical of an answer if people don't know the internals. I'm not entirely sure to which degree I should elaborate but I'll work on it.

Comment: For me it is too much technical.
I tried to get from here answer if this means that the "pipe files" are data that stored only in RAM or does not have to be stored on disk.. this is the thing I try to understand and I could not get clear answer

Comment: @gil123 In memory (be it from RAM or cache), seeing as the mentioned objects cannot be paged to the page file on the disk as they are allocated from the non-paged pool by design of the operating system

Comment: Thanks, for some reason this piece of information (that this stuff is not saved in disk even if you use the `CreateFile` function) was not clear at all and I could not find anything on the internet that state that it is not using the disk. Maybe it is only me and I missed the documentation that say it. I don't know. Anyway I think that the answer you gave to my question is very very valuable information. It is not too technical and tell thing that is the bottom line that developer may want to know.

Comment: @gil123 I haven't looked at windows source code in a while and theres still a lot more I need to find out myself but this was my current progression on named pipes just through experimenting with debuggers (livekd, ida) and sysinternals on my own computer but also looking through the ReactOS source code. The purpose of my answer was to look at the source code and basically translate in writing what didn't exist in writing on the internet already.Most of my answers are like this; I just find a question with a suitable question title to put it on, but I will eventually be putting it on a website

Comment: But this answer assumes prior knowledge of a lot of things about operating systems and underlying hardware and and what you learn on the windows internals books

Comment: Hi, don't get me wrong. I am not saying that your original answer was unless. I just said that your answer to my question was useful and good for me and maybe for most developers. It does not mean that your original answer is redundant. Both type of answers are good, one for most use-cases and the other is more to people that want to learn / build or modify operating system. I may be wrong even about this. Anyway, thank you very much for your knowledge